# Is HashBiMap threadsafe?

Tags: java, collections, guava

The docs for [com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) don't state whether it is thread-safe or not. I guess that means it isn't, but thought I'd ask in case I'm wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

HashBiMap uses multiple custom hashtables internally, which are not thread safe. You should synchronize around accesses to `HashBiMap` with:

```
Maps.synchronizedBiMap(yourHashBiMap);
```

Comment: Or better yet: Guava's [Maps.synchronizedBiMap()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#synchronizedBiMap\(com.google.common.collect.BiMap\)). This will return a BiMap object.

Comment: @CyrilleKa True. It does not cause as much functionality to get lost.

Comment: That's great, except HashBiMap has no public constructor, only the create() method. Using `Maps.synchronizedBiMap(HashBiMap.create())` seems to break Java's type inference for generics, so it has to be split into two lines.

Comment: @MikeFHay Sorry, I'm not an avid user of Guava.

Comment: Haha, no need to apologise, I'm just putting that information there for future readers :)

Comment: @hexafraction: no, it doesn't rely on `java.util.HashMap` internally, though it's still not thread-safe; it uses a custom hash table to share memory between the two directions.  @MikeFHay: you don't _have_ to split it into two lines; you can use `Maps.synchronizedBiMap(HashBiMap.<K, V>create())`.

Comment: (Fun fact: with its custom hash table, a `HashBiMap` consumes only [25%](https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures) more memory than a single one-directional `HashMap` with the same entries, where a pair of `HashMap`s would take twice as much memory.)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29), it doesn't seem synchronized to me .

```
private V More ...putInBothMaps(@Nullable K key, @Nullable V value, boolean force) {
   boolean containedKey = containsKey(key);
   if (containedKey && Objects.equal(value, get(key))) {
     return value;
   }
   if (force) {
     inverse().remove(value);
   } else {
     checkArgument(!containsValue(value), "value already present: %s", value);
   }
   V oldValue = delegate.put(key, value);
   updateInverseMap(key, containedKey, oldValue, value);
   return oldValue;
 }
```

Here `delegate` and `inverseMap` are the two `Map`s it uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

[As docs says](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html)

> A BiMap backed by two hash tables.

And

> [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is not synchronized.it must be synchronized externally. .

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is based on two hash tables. The implementation of HashMap is based on one hash table, and HashMap is not synchronized. I think it is a good rule of thumb to assume that HashBiMap requires external synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

HashBiMap internally relies on HashMaps, which are not thread safe.